# Please Help! Dual Monitor Setup with "DaisyChaining" not working on Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, multiple-monitors, display, external-monitor

my current setup is: Dell XPS 9500 and two DELL U2520D monitors. I have them connected in the following way. XPS --> USB-C in Monitor 1 --> DP out Monitor 1 --> DP in Monitor 2. I have MST turned on on the first monitor and set USB-C prioritization to "High Resolution". This setup works fine on windows. On Ubuntu on the other hand both monitors are recognized ( see xrandr output below) , but both monitors tell me "no signal" and nothing is displayed.
I found out that when prio is set to "High Resolution" on the first monitor the same problem persists even when the second monitor is disconnected from the first. When I change back to "Data Prioritization" it works fine with one monitor connected. If I connect the second monitor the first one , the first one does not display anything and the second one works fine. Please help me out guys! I would appreciate it a lot!

Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 7040 x 1440, maximum 16384 x 16384

eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 336mm x 210mm

1920x1200 59.95*+ 59.88 47.96

1920x1080 60.01 59.97 59.96 59.93

1600x1200 60.00

1680x1050 59.95 59.88

1600x1024 60.17

1400x1050 59.98

1600x900 59.99 59.94 59.95 59.82

1280x1024 60.02

1440x900 59.89

1400x900 59.96 59.88

1280x960 60.00

1440x810 60.00 59.97

1368x768 59.88 59.85

1360x768 59.80 59.96

1280x800 59.99 59.97 59.81 59.91

1152x864 60.00

1280x720 60.00 59.99 59.86 59.74

1024x768 60.04 60.00

960x720 60.00

928x696 60.05

896x672 60.01

1024x576 59.95 59.96 59.90 59.82

960x600 59.93 60.00

960x540 59.96 59.99 59.63 59.82

800x600 60.00 60.32 56.25

840x525 60.01 59.88

864x486 59.92 59.57

800x512 60.17

700x525 59.98

800x450 59.95 59.82

640x512 60.02

720x450 59.89

700x450 59.96 59.88

640x480 60.00 59.94

720x405 59.51 58.99

684x384 59.88 59.85

680x384 59.80 59.96

640x400 59.88 59.98

576x432 60.06

640x360 59.86 59.83 59.84 59.32

512x384 60.00

512x288 60.00 59.92

480x270 59.63 59.82

400x300 60.32 56.34

432x243 59.92 59.57

320x240 60.05

360x202 59.51 59.13

320x180 59.84 59.32

DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

DP-2-8 connected 2560x1440+4480+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 553mm x 311mm

2560x1440 59.95*+

2048x1280 59.99

1920x1200 59.88

2048x1080 60.00 24.00

1920x1080 60.00 50.00 59.94 24.00 23.98

1600x1200 60.00

1600x900 60.00

1280x1024 75.02 60.02

1152x864 75.00

1280x720 60.00 50.00 59.94

1024x768 75.03 60.00

800x600 75.00 60.32

720x576 50.00

720x480 60.00 59.94

640x480 75.00 60.00 59.94

720x400 70.08

DP-2-1 connected 2560x1440+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 553mm x 311mm

2560x1440 59.95*+

2048x1280 59.99

1920x1200 59.88

2048x1080 60.00 24.00

1920x1080 60.00 50.00 59.94 24.00 23.98

1600x1200 60.00

1600x900 60.00

1280x1024 75.02 60.02

1152x864 75.00

1280x720 60.00 50.00 59.94

1024x768 75.03 60.00

800x600 75.00 60.32

720x576 50.00

720x480 60.00 59.94

640x480 75.00 60.00 59.94

720x400 70.08

Comment: Is the DP signal over USB-C transferred via DP Alt Mode or encapsulated in Thunderbolt via TB Alt Mode?

Comment: its over Displayport, Its plugged into the tTB port, but neither the cable (i think) nor the monitor supports thunderbolt. Its standard DP Alt Mode i think